# How to activate a user through email verification

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, restful-authentication

Right now I am sending a confirmation link containing JWT token created for user to recipients mail address. This token is saved in a database column.

The activation link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample14/eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvcnRoLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IlJUSCIsInJvbGUiOiJVU0VSIiwiZXhwIjoxNDU2MjQ1MzM2LCJlbWFpbCI6Imtpcml0aS5rOTk5QGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.RJ54PhKcj9GGMq_VefQEMhY0x38wX1t5GgMldHCRmBZsPKoXAYg5vr39aXjHtKmIDsoqmDdzzjsrEIweWEATg3-jGe_PGfxwKZg1zsKiWlpavvKJn92VgffJi1yO54t-H31n2NKjVhAcay34pf3eUNqpPcDCEz9uf_GwSZl1ZTM
```

When the user clicks on the link, I want to be able to call a restful resource (`@Path("/public/emailActivation")`) which checks for token in database and change the account-status column from "pending" to "active"

The problem is how would I point the activation-link to rest resource method when clicked?

Is this the right approach to activate/verify user?

Rest Registration Service:

```
@Path("/public/registrationService")
public class RegistrationService {

    public RegistrationService() {
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response register(UserProfile user) {

        String email = user.getEmail();
        String token = "";

        try {
            RegistrationDAO registrationDao = new RegistrationDAO();
            int count = registrationDao.insert(user);
            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println("Registration successful");
                TokenProvider jwtProvider = new TokenProvider();
                token = jwtProvider.getToken(email);
                Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
                response.put("token", token);
                SendEmailConfirmation mailActivation = new SendEmailConfirmation();
                mailActivation.sendMail(email, "http://localhost:7070/RTH_Sample14/"+token);
                return Response.ok(response).build();
            }
            else {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).type("text/plain").entity("Registration failed!").build();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).type("text/plain").entity("Error in Login Service web service class").build();
        }
    }
}
```

This method should be called for mail activation when user clicks on link:

```
@Path("/public/emailActivation")
public class EmailActivation {


    @Path("/activate")
    public void activateAccount(){
        //Check Database for token and account status
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro ...it works